# My ggplot R library is not working in VS code

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to use ggplot in vscode. However no visual ever shows up. See below code:

'''

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(131)
data = data.frame(x1=sample(1:10,10,replace = T),
                  x2=sample(1:10,10,replace = T))
rownames(data) = 1:10
data

ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x1,y=x2))+
  geom_point(aes(size=1.2))+
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(1,10),breaks=1:10)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(1,10),breaks=1:10)+
  guides(size="none")+
  geom_text(aes(label=rownames(data)),hjust=-1.5,vjust=0.5)
```

'''

Below is a screenshot of the output:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhBul.png)

I'd really appreciate some help as to how I can start graphing on VS code. My R version is 4.3.1.